# Stored Procedure is too slow in AWS RDS Sql server

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, query-optimization, amazon-rds, performance-testing

I was migrating a legacy system to cloud (AWS). So I have two instances of the DB - One legacy DB in onprem SQL Server and the new one using AWS RDS Sql Server.

Then,There is a select statement in one of the SP which is calling a UDF to calculate one columns value.

In RDS, this statement is taking too much time where in on-prem it is not taking significant time.
Even in RDS high performance version it is taking time and the lambda getting timed out.

All the things like indeeces are all similar in both instances.

Any other reason for this performance issue??

Comment: To help you with your [tag:query-optimization] question, we need more information. Please [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/query-optimization/info), then [edit] your question.

Comment: [performance of UDF](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2020/11/how-scalar-user-defined-functions-slow-down-queries/) this explains it.

Comment: @PrebenHuybrechts - that may be true, but the OP claims that the UDF is performant when running on-prem. Do you have an explanation of how moving to AWS changes this?

Comment: Can you give us something minimal so that we can recreate this? What does your SP look like?

Comment: Are the versions of SQL Server the same? Are the database compatibility levels the same? Have you tried inspecting the execution plans to see what's different?